# Can I call a lifeless thing the ancestor of another lifeless thing?

Tags: word-usage, nouns

If the title is not understandable, I meant can I call *for example* a rock ancestor of something? I saw that the ancestor form is used for animals, plants or humans, but not for insentient stuff.

For example:

> Rocky boulder, much harder and larger than its sandy ancestor (mean sandy boulder)

Comment: Depends on what you want to get across. One could very loosely use ancestors for 'sandstone is he ancestor of limestone' if you want to get across the idea that limestone comes after a long time from sandstone. But in you sentence I don't get how you mean that a rocky boulder is the ancestor of a sandy one.

Comment: predecessor could be an option, but if you want to specifically point to a couple of jumps in the 'family tree' then ancestor should be fine.

Comment: Yes. Isn't the blunderbuss an ancestor of the AK47; Stevenson's Rocket the great-grandfather of AGV, TGV and their kin; the Wright Flyer progenitor of Concord?

Comment: You mean, can you use a metaphor?

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be more appropriate, as it's not genetic or offspring related...

an·te·ced·ent
ˌan(t)əˈsēdnt/Submit
noun
1.
a thing or event that existed before or logically precedes another.
"some antecedents to the African novel might exist in Africa's oral traditions"
synonyms:   precursor, forerunner, predecessor
"the guitar's antecedent"
adjective
adjective: antecedent
1.
preceding in time or order; previous or preexisting.
"the antecedent events that prompt you to break a diet"
synonyms:   previous, earlier, prior, preceding, precursory, former, foregoing; formalanterior
"antecedent events"